# WSO2 Identity Server: Cannot use custom claims with OAuth2

Tags: wso2, claims-based-identity, claims, wso2-identity-server

We've Installed Pre-Packaged `Identity Server 5.1.0` with API Manager 1.10.0 and use sqlserver as a data store.

We use `OAUTH2` to authorize our `API's` and we want to map our local claims to a service provider (an application?). Behind the API we have a .Net Wcf Service with some logging where we read the header with `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["assertion"]` and print the claims which are present.

The Claims which are returned are:

```
{"iss":"wso2.org/products/am"
"exp":1462357259751
"wso2url/claims/subscriber":"Sjaak"
"wso2url/claims/applicationid":"1003"
"wso2url/claims/applicationname":"DefaultApplication"
"wso2url/claims/applicationtier":"Medium"
"wso2url/claims/apicontext":"/Test/v1.0"
"wso2url/claims/version":"v1.0"
"wso2url/claims/tier":"Silver"
"wso2url/claims/keytype":"PRODUCTION"
"wso2url/claims/usertype":"APPLICATION"
"wso2url/claims/enduser":"Sjaak@carbon.super"
"wso2url/claims/enduserTenantId":"-1234"
"wso2url/claims/emailaddress":"sjakie@chocola.nl"
"wso2url/claims/givenname":"Sjakie"
"wso2url/claims/lastname":"van de Chocoladefabriek"
"wso2url/claims/role":"Internal/subscriber
Internal/everyone
Application/Sjaak_DefaultApplication_PRODUCTION"}
```

Where wso2url is http://wso2.org, but we cannot post this, because I don't have 10 reputation points...:(

The information in these claims is good, but only we want to use our own uri, so not wso2.org, but myorg.com. And we want to add other claims, with for example our own userId and some other stuff.

Among other things we have followed the guide for configuring claims for a service provider but had no success with this. We have made the assumption that an application  is a service provider for which we can use the claims.

Has anyone got an idea what we are doing wrong? What do we need to do to add custom claims?

Thanks in advance!

[Added on 9th may]
Maybe this can point us in the right direction?
When we add a subscription to an application and we generate a new key than there is no new Service provider in the list:
[The list of service provider without a new one for user Sjaak, so there is missing: Sjaak_CalculatorApp_PRODUCTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldo8z.png)

But even when we do this for user admin the claims are not coming through. We have the following claim configuration and in my logging still the same claims as described above are there, no new ones, so no claim named accountnaam and no voogd.com uri:

Answer (score 0):

Service Provider(SP) - It provides services to some end users and relies on a trusted Identity provider(IDP) to handle authentication and authorization for them. SP may use multiple protocols(Oauth2, SAML2, etc.) to communicate with IDP.

Claims are defined for SP, since same claims can be send over different protocols. In the default case, Identity server uses wso2 claim dialect(start with wos2.com) for claims. If you want a different claim dialect than this, use "Define Custom Claim Dialect" option in the service provider configuration. In there you can map wso2 claims(Local Claim) to your own claims(Service Provider Claim).

Comment: I have recently tried this approach and it works fine for the scenario asked in question.

Comment: It's good to know that what we want can work, but despite your answers (thank you for them @Thanuja) we can't get it to work. Maybe we've got a lead on what goes wrong, because when we add a new application in the store and we subscribe with an other user than admin to this app, there is no new Service Provider created. When we do the same for admin we get something like in the service provider list:                                        Service Provider ID: admin_CalculatorApp_PRODUCTION with Description: Service Provider for application admin_CalculatorApp_PRODUCTION